# jQuery replace all instances of a file path

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to replace all instances of a image file path on a page.

Specifically, I'm having trouble escaping the forward slashes in the images' file path.

So for instance, I need to replace the following:

```
src="/directory/directory/file.jpg"
```

with

```
src="directory/directory/file.jpg"
```

So, I need to get rid of the leading forward slash.

I was wanting to use the str.replace as follows:

```
str.replace(/string/g, "other string");
```

But, I can't get it to escape the double quotes or the forward slash.

Help?

Thanks!!

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif

Comment: Have you tried replacing the url using the `.attr()` function? You wouldn't need to escape the quotes then.
`$(element).attr('src', 'other string');`

Comment: This wouldn't work because there numerous image files being called on the page, but not all would need to be changed... just those with the specific file path string. Further, there's not a common class by which to select just those.